# Generate predicted values from a mixed model with intercept removed

Tags: r, predict, lme4, intercept

I'm having some trouble using predictInterval to generate predicted values from my lmer mixed model with the intercept removed.

the simulated dataset

```
logreads <- rep(1:16, 20)
arthropod <- rep(c("mealworm", "spider"), 160)
bird <- rep(c("GY", "NF"), 160)
noop <- rep(c("WOTH293", "WOTH294"), 16)
massin <- rnorm(160, mean=10, sd=5) 
m8 <-  data.frame(cbind(logreads, arthropod, massin, bird, noop)) 
colnames(m8) <- c("logreads", "arthropod", "massin", "bird", "noop")
m8$massin <- as.numeric(as.character(m8$massin))
m8$logreads <- as.numeric(as.character(m8$logreads))
```

the model, with intercept removed

```
library(lme4)
lm1 <- lmer(logreads ~ 0 + arthropod*massin + (1|bird) + (1|noop), data=m8, REML=FALSE)
```

building prediction matrix

```
arthropod <- rep(c("mealworm"), 16)
bird <- rep(c("GY"), 16)
noop <- rep(c("WOTH293"), 16)
massin <- 0:15 
pred.mx <-  data.frame(cbind(arthropod, massin, bird, noop)) 
colnames(pred.mx) <- c("arthropod", "massin", "bird", "noop")
pred.mx$massin <- as.numeric(as.character(pred.mx$massin))
```

calculating the predicted values

```
library("merTools")
predictInterval(lm1, newdata=pred.mx, level=0.95, n.sims=999, include.resid.var=FALSE)
```

I get the error *"Error in model.frame.default(subbars(formula(merMod)), data = newdata) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'arthropod')"*

In other iterationw (with the real data) I get *"Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'logreads' not found"*

`preds(lm1)` #note that this works just fine

predictInterval() works just fine on the same model as above but removing the "+0" ie the command that removes the intercept

I believe that by specifying "+0", predictInterval() to loosing track of the columns in newdata, but I'm note sure it is a bug or an error in my code.

Note that I don't mind the warning messages as the data here are simulated. I've also updated to the latest version of merTools (0.5) that claims to have fixed this problem with intercept-removed models, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: `predict(lm1, newdata=pred.mx)` works, so I suggest this might be a bug.